# Overlay images on one another in outlook (absolute positioning)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, zurb-foundation

I'm struggling to find a cross-email-client way of stacking images on top of one another. I'm looking for something that would also work for Outlook. I am also using the inky templating language from foundation/zurb, although I can still write whatever html/css I want.

I had successfully used http://blog.gorebel.com/absolute-positioning-in-email/ trick of 0-width/height container with overflow to make it work on all other email clients, only Outlook is the bad child.

Has anyone got tricks to overlay images (not backgrounds) on top of one another in Outlook ?

EDIT

The target : https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0a7D.jpg
As you can see on this image, the "header" of the card has two images : one classic avatar as a rounded image, and the same "avatar" has some filters applied and is used as background image with a special rounder corner

*NOTE : I am the blurr filters/round corners are unavailable on some email client, we'll have alternative code to cope with that on those email clients that are not supported*

The absolute positioning code I was using before (I am in the process of rewriting divs to use inky's rows/columns that transform the code to use tables

```
<div class="professional-card">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="absolute-wrapper">
            <div class="avatar-background-wrapper absolute-in-wrapper">
                <%= avatar_img(class: 'avatar-background') %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="absolute-wrapper">
            <div class="avatar employee %> absolute-in-wrapper">
                <%= avatar_img %>
                <div class="firstname">
                    <%= model.user.first_name %>
                </div>
                <div class="company-name">
                    <%= model.company_name %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="absolute-wrapper">
            <div class="absolute-in-wrapper">
                <div class="position">
                    <%= model.position %>
                </div>
                <ul class="tags">
                    <%= tags %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="absolute-wrapper">
            <div class="absolute-in-wrapper">
                <div class="company-logo">
                    <%= logo_img %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The absolute positioning SCSS code corresponding to the mentioned trick (that is automatically inlined in the message)

```
.absolute-in-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.absolute-wrapper {
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can get background images to work in Outlook is to use VML.

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0000; width:600px;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
  <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" color="#ff0000"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="450" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; font-family: Arial, san-serif;">
          Background Image with text on top
        </h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can find most of this code at https://backgrounds.cm.

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/7zLaLrfx/

**Rounded Corners**

If you have a technique with rounded corners with Outlook, please post your solution. `border-radius:` does not work with Outlook 2007-2016.

**Absolute Positioning**

`position:` does not work in Outlook, Gmail or related email programs. Even the page where you posted about alternatives doesn't work in Outlook. The best way to overcome position issues is to design an email where it's not a requirement.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/

**Use Spacers**

One alternative is to use spacer tables. This is one way you can add space.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="8" style="padding: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 2px; font-size: 0;">
      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answers, it would seem there is no other solution but to use background image if one wishes to stack two images on top of one another... However in the current state, I do not have the final "background image" to display. On my website I am applying a filter to have the background image either blurred when supported, or with a dark overlay. Is it possible to apply some filters / darken th background image using VML ? I found little resources regarding what VML supports. Or do I have to generate this image server-side ?

Comment: I ended up server-side generating the background image with filters applied through ImageMagick